# LyX AMS align environment multiple columns

Tags: latex, lyx

When I choose to insert an AMS Align environment in LyX, I only get two columns. I am pretty sure it is possible to get multiple columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that there is an "add column" button that appears in the math toolbar.
[image]